# Greasemonkey: Adding print button - print and 'print friendly' style div

Tags: greasemonkey

I have created a greasemonkey script for the purpose of:

- Add print receipt button to 3rd party web app page
- Add receipt printer friendly styles to div in new window
- print this window

The button shows up, but it doesn't trigger my function, which at this point just prints the div.

Here's where I'm at:

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';

scriptElement.innerHTML =  'function printReceipt() { \
var divToPrint=document.getEelementById("loanTable"); \
newWin= window.open(""); \
newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML); \
newWin.print(); \
newWin.close(); \
}';

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptElement);

window.addButton = function () {
    // Get the location on the page where you want to create the button
    var targetDiv = document.getElementById('newcheckout');

    // Create a div to surround the button
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'autoCheckOrder');

    // Create the button and set its attributes
    var inputButton = document.createElement('input');
    inputButton.name = 'autoCheckOrderButton';
    inputButton.type = 'button';
    inputButton.value = 'Print Receipt?';
    inputButton.setAttribute("onclick", "printReceipt();");

    // Append the button to the div
    newDiv.appendChild(inputButton); 
    targetDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
}
addButton();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo on this line:

```
var divToPrint=document.getEelementById("loanTable"); \
```

Change it to:

```
var divToPrint=document.getElementById("loanTable"); \
```

---

Alternately, add this line to your script's [metadata section](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block):

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
```

Then the whole script becomes:

```js
$("#newcheckout").append ('<div id="autoCheckOrder"></div>');
$("#autoCheckOrder").append ('<button>Print Receipt?</button>');

$("#autoCheckOrder button").click ( function () {
    var divToPrint  = document.getElementById ("loanTable"); 
    var newWin      = window.open (""); 
    newWin.document.write (divToPrint.outerHTML); 
    newWin.print(); 
    newWin.close(); 
} );
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot ...can't believe how much time spelling errors kill.

Comment: One thing though ...it doesn't print the table I was targeting. Says 'undefined'.

Comment: Works fine in my tests.  You aren't trying to do cross-domain, right?  Is the content added by AJAX?  In an iframe? ... Might start a new question and list the exact full script and the exact target page.

Comment: Did this    newWin.document.write ( $("#loanTable").html() ); -- now it works!

Comment: Any ideas why this doesn't work in Chrome using tampermonkey?

Comment: I'll take a look at your latest question when I get some free time (several hours).  Chrome is a bit of a pain with its sandbox.